# trying to auto submit form after text input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

Here is how the form is supposed to execute:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click(function(){

        //access token stuff
        var token = $("#link_input").val(); ... etc</script>
```

.

I am trying to auto submit this info once it exceeds 10 characters. Normally you fill out the text area in the input field and you click submit. Upon clicking the submit button the JS validates the text in the input box and if it's valid it executes. How can I auto-submit the text in the input box without having to click the submit button?

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
var x=10;//nr characters 
function submitT(t,f){ 
if(t.value.length==x){ 
f.submit() 
} 
} 
</script> 


                    <input id="link_input" onkeyup="submitT(this,this.form)" autofocus="true" autocomplete="off" placeholder="http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=AAAZDCiOS6Ls0BAMUKJDvLZCTgZDZD" style="width: 600px;margin-left: -11%;" value="" name="url">

                    <br/>



<div id="Wait" style="display:none;"><center>Processing your form<br><img src="http://i.imgur.com/kKqSe.gif"></center></div>

                    <br/>


                    <center>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="submit" onkeyup="submitT(this,this.form)" autofocus="true"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/eA6fv.png" style="border:0px;padding-top:5px;"></a>
```

Comment: `this.form` is false..get the form by `document.getElementById('yourFormId')`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#link_input').on('keyup', function() { 
    if($(this).val().length > 10) {
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: what do i change and replace?

Comment: @computerquotes well, my suggestion is to remove all your current mess, create a complete structured form. Inside your form, give your input that you want to submit the form if more than 10 characters are typed an id `link_input`.

Answer (score 2):

Just test against keyup similar to what you have already.

```
<form action='someplace' id='myform' method='post'>
  <input type='text' id='link_input' ...other stuff />
</form>
```

jquery:

```
$('#link_input').on('keyup',function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  var len = val.length;

  if(len == 10){
    $('#myform').submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: i assume by 'someplace' you mean a php file. the script is supposed to be clientside

Comment: @computerquotes 'someplace' is where ever you want to send the information.  Generally people submit forms to send information to a backend script, like php or whatever language. Are you trying to submit this to javascript?

Comment: yea. the information contained in the imput field is supposed to be processed clientside

Comment: @computerquotes Ok. Then there is no reason to submit it.  The jquery/javascript can grab the info from the input and process it without submittion. How exactly do you want to process the input info?

Comment: @computerquotes don't forget to verify the length at the other end of the server, users without javascript can easiely bypass this.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your btn from submit to btnSubmit.

The id of submit is going to mess with f.submit()