# How to automatically submit form when input is inserted?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to auto submit my form when value is inserted in the "**Thumb_Print_Code**" Field. below is my form.  I want to do this without clicking on save nutton
**Im working on Php Laravel Framework.**

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('added') }}" id="myform">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="Thumb_Print_Code" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Thumb Print Code') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="Thumb_Print_Code" type="int" class="form-control @error('Thumb_Print_Code') is-invalid @enderror" name="Thumb_Print_Code" value="{{ old('Thumb_Print_Code') }}" required autocomplete="Thumb_Print_Code">

                            @error('Thumb_Print_Code')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Save Attendance ') }}
                            </button>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Please let me know how can I achieve my end goals ?

Comment: Have you tried adding a keydown listener that checks the value and then submits the document form?

Comment: I tried different codes, but unfortunately didn't succeed.

Comment: and where to add keyword Listener ?

Comment: What did you try?  Can you please post it?  (The code for the listener.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trying to auto submit form after text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838827/trying-to-auto-submit-form-after-text-input)

Comment: `<script>
                        $('Thumb_Print_Code').on('keyup',function(){
                         var val = $(this).val();       
                         if(len == 10){
                             $('myform').submit();
                           }
                              });
                    </script>`

Comment: `<input id="Thumb_Print_Code" type="int" class="form-control @error('Thumb_Print_Code') is-invalid @enderror" name="Thumb_Print_Code" value="{{ old('Thumb_Print_Code') }}" required autocomplete="Thumb_Print_Code" oninput="function()">` Thing that I have tried so far

Comment: Add code to answer so it's easier to read?  I think `if(len == 10)` might be not right?  But, I could see better if it was nicely formatted.

Comment: It looks like you took that from sta's post.  It seems clear to me what needs to be edited there to fix this: `var val = $(this).val();
  var len = val.length;

  if(len == 10){
    $('#myform').submit();
  }`  Btw, that is jQuery, your post is flagged JavaScript.

Comment: Im beginner, really do not have knowledge about javascript and jquery.